# How to set connection timeout for app in F5 BIGIP Device

Tags: tcp, load-balancing, f5

I have an application A how to change the Connection Timeout for the application A in F5 BIGIP Load Balancer.

How to set the connection timeout to 1000sec's.

Please guide to me to setup the connection timeout.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is done in the tcp profile (Local Traffic->Profiles->Protocol->TCP.) I'd recommend you create a custom profile with tcp as the parent (or one of the optimized tcp profiles as parent) and then change the default idle timeout of 300 seconds to 1000.